# The difference between unquoted, single-quoted, and double-quoted array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I know that it's more performant to use single-quoting versus double-quoting when accessing/processing string values, but I was wondering if there's any performance benefits in omitting the quotations entirely.

```
$a = array('table' => 'myTable');

$table = $a['table'];
```

versus

```
$a = array(table => 'myTable');

$table = $a[table];
```

Comment: It is really, really, really, bad practice not to quote the array index if it is a string.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a practice that is not only bad but easily considered WRONG. As others have pointed out, what you are suggesting is an undocumented 'feature' of PHP which may not always exist in future updates of the language.

Comment: As Norse said $table = $a['table'] is faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In your second example the PHP processor checks if "table" is defined as a constant before defaulting it back to an array key, so it is making one more check than it needs to. This can also create problems.

Consider this:

```
const table = 'text';

$a = array( table => 'myTable', order => 'myOrder' );

$table = $a[table]
```

Now PHP interprets your array as $a[text] which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You should always quote your strings. In your second example, PHP does convert `table` and `order` to strings, but if `table` or `order` were [defined](http://php.net/define) as constants, PHP would use the value of the constant instead of the string 'table' or 'order'.

Answer (score 1):

The difference, according to research, between "string" and 'string' is so negligible as to be non-existent.  Not that it matters much, BUT it's faster to do

```
echo "this is {$var1} and {$var2} and {$var3}";
```

than it is to

```
echo 'this is ' . $var1 . ' and ' . $var2 . ' and ' . $var3;
```